# Closed expression and physical interpretation of the median

Tags: statistics, means, visualization, median

Opposed to the arithmetic mean there is no immediate closed expression for the median of a distribution $n(x)$ of a variable $x\in\mathbb{N}$ over a population of $N$ items, at least not when introducing the median to novices.

[image]

The **arithmetic mean** is just

> $$\bar{x} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}x\ n(x)$$

with $N = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}n(x)$. Physically interpreted the arithmetic mean is the value of the point of mechanical equilibrium $\blacktriangle$ of the above arrangement of items (each having the same weight), shifted by $0.5$:

[image]

Now let $N$ be odd. Then the **median** is usually introduced like this:

> Sort all items by their value $x$. The median is the value of the
>   $\frac{N+1}{2}$th item.

Physically interpreted the median is the value of the item at the point of mechanical equilibrium of **this** arrangement of items:

[image]

---

It turns out that one may get a concise closed expression for the median that has immediately to do with this definition and interpretation of the median.

First define the distribution function $n_\leq(X)$ which gives the number of items with value $x \leq X$ (not equal $X$ as in the original distribution):

$$n_\leq(X) = \sum_{x=0}^X n(x)$$

The plot of $n_\leq(x)$ looks like this:

[image]

Since this function is monotonic there's a well-defined inverse $n_\leq^{-1}$  which looks like this (reflexion at the diagonal):

[image]

or like this:

[image]

or like this:

[image]

Note that this inverse function can be interpreted easily: it gives the value of the $n$th item when the items were sorted (somehow) by $x$.

Now the median is just the value of the inverse function $n_\leq^{-1}$ (for which we have a closed expression) for the argument $\frac{N+1}{2}$:

[image]

*[Side note: The number $n$ changed its character in the course of the transformations $n(x) \rightarrow n_\leq \rightarrow n_\leq^{-1} \rightarrow x(n)$. In $n(x)$, $n$ is a **cardinal** number, in $x(n)$, $n$ is a **ordinal** number.]*

My questions are:

> 1. Is there a standard reference where this way of gently introducing the median is chosen?
> 2. Can it be understood physically that the arithmetic mean equals the median iff $n(x)$ is symmetric with respect to some $x_0$, i.e. $n(x_0 - x) = n(x_0 +x)$?
> 3. How does one call and interpret the inverse function $p_\leq^{-1}$ in case of a continuous probability distribution $p(x)$ (when there are not items to be sorted
>      anymore)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I'm not sure about standard references. But the usual definition

> Sort all items by their value x. The median is the value of the $\frac{N+1}{2}$th
>   item.

is excessively procedural, and refers to a slower-than-needed algorithm. A better definition nearby is:

> The median is an $x$ such that at least half the values are $\ge x$, and at least half the values are $\le x$.

2) Yes. Here is one physical intepretation with the symmetry:

> Suppose you have a 2-d object of uniform density, with a vertical line
>   of symmetry through $p$.  Then putting your finger directly underneath
>   $p$ both balances the object [$p$ is in the same line as the mean
>   location] and gets equal weight on both sides [$p$ is in the same line
>   as the median location]. So the mean and median location are the same.

By contrast, if you take an L shape, putting your finger in the median location will cause the L to fall over to the right.

3) The inverse of the cumulative probability function is called the **quantile function**. There's rarely a closed form for it, even when the cumulative probability function has a closed form, but even so I'm surprised it's so often neglected.